# How to get net encap in c\c++ on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking

- Is there a way in Linux, using C\C++ code, to get the information about all network adapters "Link encap:*****"? I had already got things like IP address and MAC address.
- Here's sample output from ifconfig:

  ```
  ethx  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:20:CF:8B:42
        inet addr:217.149.127.10  Bcast:217.149.127.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:2472694671 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:44641779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:1761467179 (1679.8 Mb)  TX bytes:2870928587 (2737.9 Mb)
        Interrupt:28
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the struct `ifreq` in the `<net/if.h>`

```
/* Interface request structure used for socket ioctl's. All interface ioctl's must have
parameter definitions which begin with ifr_name. The remainder may be interface specific. */

struct ifreq
  {
# define IFHWADDRLEN 6
# define IFNAMSIZ IF_NAMESIZE
    union
      {
        char ifrn_name[IFNAMSIZ]; /* Interface name, e.g. "en0". */
      } ifr_ifrn;

    union
      {
        struct sockaddr ifru_addr;
        struct sockaddr ifru_dstaddr;
        struct sockaddr ifru_broadaddr;
        struct sockaddr ifru_netmask;
        struct sockaddr ifru_hwaddr;
        short int ifru_flags;
        int ifru_ivalue;
        int ifru_mtu;
        struct ifmap ifru_map;
        char ifru_slave[IFNAMSIZ]; /* Just fits the size */
        char ifru_newname[IFNAMSIZ];
         __caddr_t ifru_data;
      } ifr_ifru;
  };
# define ifr_name ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name /* interface name */
# define ifr_hwaddr ifr_ifru.ifru_hwaddr /* MAC address */
# define ifr_addr ifr_ifru.ifru_addr /* address */
# define ifr_dstaddr ifr_ifru.ifru_dstaddr /* other end of p-p lnk */
# define ifr_broadaddr ifr_ifru.ifru_broadaddr /* broadcast address */
# define ifr_netmask ifr_ifru.ifru_netmask /* interface net mask */
# define ifr_flags ifr_ifru.ifru_flags /* flags */
# define ifr_metric ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue /* metric */
# define ifr_mtu ifr_ifru.ifru_mtu /* mtu */
# define ifr_map ifr_ifru.ifru_map /* device map */
# define ifr_slave ifr_ifru.ifru_slave /* slave device */
# define ifr_data ifr_ifru.ifru_data /* for use by interface */
# define ifr_ifindex ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue /* interface index */
# define ifr_bandwidth ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue /* link bandwidth */
# define ifr_qlen ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue /* queue length */
# define ifr_newname ifr_ifru.ifru_newname /* New name */
# define _IOT_ifreq _IOT(_IOTS(char),IFNAMSIZ,_IOTS(char),16,0,0)
# define _IOT_ifreq_short _IOT(_IOTS(char),IFNAMSIZ,_IOTS(short),1,0,0)
# define _IOT_ifreq_int _IOT(_IOTS(char),IFNAMSIZ,_IOTS(int),1,0,0)
```

Comment: With a link to the header doc and maybe a short example, this could be a good answer ;)

Comment: I do not found the  field which return "Link encap"(net type).           
ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr)-------->get ip